# Creating tables based on subqueries

Tags: sql

I have been trying to create a new table by capturing some columns and concatenating some of them together. I have have tried different variations but no joy. Currently I get an error that a column name is missing or empty.

```
select [company_code] 
        ,[ftds_opening_balance]
        ,[ftds_closing_balance]
        ,(select [prime_account_code]+'-'+[sub_account_code] as GL_Account
        from [output].[trial_balance]
            )
into[output].[trial_balance2013]
from [output].[trial_balance]
where period_year = '2013'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part that get the error is probably

```
    ,(select [prime_account_code]+'-'+[sub_account_code] as GL_Account
    from [output].[trial_balance]
        )
```

in some DB that will give you a message that there is more than one value.
It's the same table already in the query, so getting the values from there will give you the same result.

```
select [company_code] 
     , [ftds_opening_balance]
     , [ftds_closing_balance]
     , [prime_account_code] + '-' + [sub_account_code] as GL_Account
into   [output].[trial_balance2013]
from   [output].[trial_balance]
where  period_year = '2013'
```

Not all the DB use '+' to concatenate string, for example Oracle uses || so the calculated column should be

```
    ,[prime_account_code] || '-' || [sub_account_code] as GL_Account
```

also `prime_account_code` and `sub_account_code` should be a string datatype, or converted to a string datatype to be able to concatenate them

Comment: Thank you. I was overcomplicating it for myself